# How to insert multiple values in single row in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hey i'm stuck on SQL problem from past 4 days,how i insert multiple values for single row 
for example-project table holds projects names,id, and other details where employee holds employee details,there is many to many relation in project and employee,so i want to store many employees working in single or multiple projects. plz  help me out.....

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to create a new table saying `employeeproject` which will have a foreign key from employee table and from project table and primary key of its own table. So your new table will look like this

```
employeeproject ==> epid, emp_id, proj_id
```

In many-to-many relationship always we need to create a table which links (maps) these two tables
Refer [here](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html)

Hope this helps!